# Как добавить цифру к каждому элементу списка?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, map

Делаю импорт из .xlsx
Получаю вот такой df:

```
my.dtypes
Период     datetime64[ns]
Телефон            object
dtype: object
```

Сам датафрейм выглядит вот так:

```
    Период       Телефон
0   2021-01-01  8312333666; 9101054581; 8312617706
1   2021-01-08  9307167823
2   2021-01-08  9307167823
3   2021-01-11  9200211539; 9200239899; 9519012568
4   2021-01-11  9108917638
```

Каким образом можно добавить к каждому номеру в каждом списке цифру '8', чтобы получилось
вот так:

```
Период       Телефон
0   2021-01-01  88312333666; 89101054581; 88312617706
1   2021-01-08  89307167823
2   2021-01-08  89307167823
3   2021-01-11  89200211539; 89200239899; 89519012568
4   2021-01-11  89108917638
```

Делаю вот так, но добавляет только первому элементу в списке:

```
country_code = "8"
my['Телефон'] = country_code + my['Телефон'].map(str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение для измененного вопроса (в изначальной версии данные были представлены списками, а не CSV строками):

```
In [154]: df
Out[154]:
                                phone
0  8312333666; 9101054581; 8312617706
1                          9307167823
2                                 NaN
3  9200211539; 9200239899; 9519012568

In [155]: df["phone"] = ("8" + df["phone"].dropna().str.split(";\s*").explode()).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: "; ".join(x))

In [156]: df
Out[156]:
                                   phone
0  88312333666; 89101054581; 88312617706
1                            89307167823
2                                    NaN
3  89200211539; 89200239899; 89519012568
```

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
Вылезла ошибка. Хотя есть только номера телефонов и нули.

Comment: @bboris, у вас некоторые номера прочитались как числа, а некоторые как строки - убедитесь, что вы читаете все данные из данного столбца __как строки__ и указанная вами проблема исчезнет

Comment: Да, все отработало как надо. Спасибо!

Comment: @bboris, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)

Answer (score 3):

Исходный фрейм:

```
In [138]: df
Out[138]:
                                    phone
0               [8312437527,  9023099753]
1                                     NaN
2                                     NaN
3  [8312477313,  8314148820,  9202539919]
4  [8312477313,  8314148820,  9202539919]
```

решение:

```
df.loc[df["phone"].notna(), "phone"] = \
    (df
     .loc[df["phone"].notna(), "phone"]
     .map(lambda x: ["8" + y.lstrip() for y in x]))
```

результат:

```
In [140]: df
Out[140]:
                                     phone
0               [88312437527, 89023099753]
1                                      NaN
2                                      NaN
3  [88312477313, 88314148820, 89202539919]
4  [88312477313, 88314148820, 89202539919]
```

Comment: Не много не так отработало почему то: 
[88, 89, 80, 88, 82, 83, 86, 80, 89, 84, 82]

к каждой цирфе добавилась 8-ка.

Comment: @bboris, Я создал фрейм из данных из вашего вопроса `df = pd.DataFrame({"phone": data})` и код из ответа замечательно отработал. Приведите в вопросе код для создания __воспроизводимого__ примера данных - похоже у вас данные не совсем такие как вы представили в вопросе...